# How to move a single TickLabel

Tags: labeling, ticks

my code is

```
Beta0 = Import["beta0_Monatsende.xls"];

b0 = DateListPlot[Beta0, PlotRange -> Full, 
FrameLabel -> {{Style["\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Beta]\), \(0\)]\)", 
   Bold, Medium], " "}, {Style["Zeit [Monat]", Bold, Medium], 
  Style["Parameter \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Beta]\), \(0\)]\)", 
   Bold, FontSize -> 16]}}, LabelStyle -> Directive[Medium], 
FrameTicks -> {{LinTicks[0, 14, 2, 2], 
  LinTicks[0, 14, 2, 2, 
   ShowTickLabels -> False]}, {{{1972, 09}, {1975, 09}, {1978, 
    09}, {1981, 09}, {1984, 09}, {1987, 09}, {1990, 09}, {1993, 
    09}, {1996, 09}, {1999, 09}, {2002, 09}, {2005, 09}, {2008, 
    09}, {2011, 09}, {2014, 09}, {2017, 09}, {2018, 08}}, 
  Automatic}}, 
DateTicksFormat -> {"MonthNameShort", " ", "Year"}] /. 
x : (FrameTicks -> _) :>MapAt[# /. s_String :> Rotate[s, \[Pi]/3] &, x, {2, 2, 1}]
```

Before I load the "CustomTicks.m" package

And i get the following graph

[image]

Is it possible to move the Ticklabel "Sep 2017" a little bit more to the left? Or to center the labels directly under the ticks?

Comment: You could rotare the lables by `Pi/2`.

Comment: I had that solution before but in my opinion it looks better with a Pi/3 rotation